# How can I compare two Oracle Databases that cannot be reached from the same machine?

Tags: oracle11g, compare

I need to compare two Oracle 11g Data Bases (Producción and Testing) but both Data Bases cannot be reached from the same PC. Basically I need to know if the packages are on the same version (same number of lines by example).

Comment: How about getting a hash of the source for each (from `all_source` or user/DBA versions), for a more accurate comparison than just a line count? Or pull the source from as text and compare elsewhere?

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean with getting a hash?

Comment: I mean passing the source code [through a hash function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_crypto.htm#i1002022). You'd have to build your source code (stored line by line in `dba_source`) into a CLOB to pass into that function, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a comment, rather than just counting lines (which doesn't necessarily tell you much), you could generate a hash of the stored source code on each system, and then manually compare the hashes; for instance using a simple package created as a test:

```
create or replace package p42 as
  procedure foo(bar number);
end p42;
/

create or replace package body p42 as
  procedure foo(bar number) is
  begin
    /* Some comment */
    null;
  end foo;
end p42;
/

set serveroutput on
declare
  l_clob clob;
  l_hash raw(64);
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, false);
  for cur in (
    select text from user_source where type = 'PACKAGE BODY' and name = 'P42'
  ) loop
    dbms_lob.append(l_clob, cur.text);
  end loop;

  l_hash := dbms_crypto.Hash (l_clob, dbms_crypto.hash_sh1);
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_clob);

  dbms_output.put_line(l_hash);
end;
/

57853368B7B4CBBA53F17A50833C1DC2DF8C666A


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If I modify the package body, here just adding an 's' in the comment string, I get a different hash:

```
create or replace package body p42 as
  procedure foo(bar number) is
  begin
    /* Some comments */
    null;
  end foo;
end p42;
/
```

then executing the same anonymous block shows:

```
24E49A4C55E036FFD34D8A01295A6514E1AAD0FD


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If the hash value is different, the source is different. It's always possible to get collisions of course, but it's very unlikely you would in this scenario.

It doesn't tell you *what* is different. You would have to extract the code and compare it in more detail for that. But as a fairly quick and simple check that you have what you expect this is easier.

Comment: I got PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared

Comment: Mmm, guess that isn't public by default, or the public synonym has been dropped as a security measure. Your DBA might have to grant you execute on that. Which may or may not be a problem politically...

Answer (score 0):

Long way:

Go to a PC in which you can reach the production database, run this command:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source
  where type = 'PACKAGE'
  and owner = 'SOME_SCHEMA'
```

Export results to, say, excel or something.

Take to your other oracle box.  Run that same command.  Export results to another file.  Use some file comparing tool.

Easy way:

"IF" you can get access from the same PC, a tool such as Toad for Oracle can easily do object comparisons between different databases.

Comment: How can I just count the lines of each package to do a quick review?

Comment: SELECT name, count(line)
  FROM dba_source
  where type = 'PACKAGE'
  and owner = 'SOME_SCHEMA'
  group by name

Comment: Careful though... this will NOT necessarily reflect if packages are different or not.  Could have in-line edits that wouldn't cause new lines to be generated for example.

Comment: yeap. I did a number of lines comparison and is the same.

Comment: what about of counting the characters on each package? How can you do that?